# Selecting an element in a list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list made up by two turtles (for simplicity, `houses` and `landlords`). 
Thanks to some suggestions that were provided me here, I selected the house with maximum price from the list, but unfortunately the landlord is not the owner of that house, but only the turtle selected one tick before. 
I understood that something is going wrong with the definition of this turtle. 
What I wrote, after the suggestions, is:

```
    let selected_house max-one-of turtle-set my-list [price]
    let selected_landlord [my-landlord] of selected_house
       print (word "Landlord" [selected_landlord] of selected_house)
    let new_list (list selected_house selected_landlord)

       print (word  "Landlord " selected_landlord "of house: " selected_house " by price: " [price] of selected_house)
```

but if, let's say, I have:

List:

```
"Landlord 2 is the owner of house 4 by price 400000"
"Landlord 5 is the owner of house 1 by price 100000"
"Landlord 4 is the owner of house 3 by price 300000"
```

and then I use `selected_house/landlord` to select the owner of the house with highest price, I should get `(house 4, landlord 2)`; however, I am getting `(house 4, landlord 5)`, i.e. the landlord selected one tick before.

I defined the landlord and house as follows (I have similar exercises, but on different topics):

```
if breed = landlords [

          hatch-houses n_house [

            set price precision (random-float 1) 3

            set this-house self
            set this-landlord myself

            ask myself [

              set my-list fput (list this-house this-landlord) my-list

            ]
        ]
```

where `this-house` and `this-landlord` are globals and `my-list` is `landlords' own`.

Could you please help me to understand and fix the issue with this part of code?

I thought that, as I am creating the list with the first element = house and the second element = landlord, it could be possible add some condition to make the selection as easy as possible (for example, once selecting the first item, i.e. house with highest price, set the second item of each element in the list as landlord of a house).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `this-house` and `this-landlord` are globals, and I think (without the full code to go on) that this may be your problem. If I understand your model, each landlord has a set of houses, and you want to be able to find the most expensive house and the landlord that owns it. If each house keeps track of its landlord and price,  and each landlord keeps track of their houses, then that should allow you to link any house to its landlord, or to look at all the houses that a landlord owns.

The following model perhaps will give you one idea of how to proceed.  It creates landlords, each of which then creates houses with a random price. It then finds the most expensive house and its landlord.  Then for each landlord, it finds that landlord's most expensive house.  The landlord could keep a list of houses with [house landlord], but the second item would be the same for all the landlord's houses.

```
breed [landlords landlord]
breed [houses house]

landlords-own [my-houses my-house-list]
houses-own [price my-landlord]

to test
  clear-all
  create-landlords 10
  ask landlords [
    hatch-houses 5 [
      set price precision (random-float 1) 3
      set my-landlord myself
    ]
    set my-houses houses with [my-landlord = myself]
  ]

  let most-expensive max-one-of houses [price]
  show (word "The mostexpensive house is house " most-expensive " owned by " [my-landlord] of most-expensive " with price =" [price] of most-expensive)

  ask landlords [
    let my-most-expensive max-one-of my-houses [price]
    show (word "landlord " self "'s most expensive house is house " most-expensive " with price =" [price] of my-most-expensive)
  ]
end
```

On the other hand, you could keep a list of all houses across all landlords as a global, and if you run `list-houses` after test, you will get such a list, which you can then sort by price, landlord, or whatever.

```
globals [house-list]

to list-houses
  set house-list []
  ask houses [
    set house-list fput (list self my-landlord price) house-list
  ]
  show house-list
  let sorted-by-price sort-by [[a b] -> item 2 a > item 2 b] house-list
  let most-expensive first sorted-by-price
  show (word "the most expensive house is house " item 0 most-expensive " with owner " item 1 most-expensive " and price " item 2 most-expensive)
end
```